# addBatch() execution in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

The problem with the below code is that suppose if a particular query in queries[] array consist of an error , the statement query would execute and an exception for the query with error would be thrown , i want both the queries to be executed iff both queries are error free or else none should be executed , what should i do to the code below to get desired Results? pls help .

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int rw = jTable1.getRowCount();
        int col = jTable1.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("RC" + rw);
        System.out.println("Col" + col);
        String queries[] = new String[rw];
        Object o[][] = new Object[rw][col];
        String poid = jComboBox10.getSelectedItem().toString();
        java.sql.Date xdate = null;
        Connection con=null;
        Statement st=null;
       String cc = ims.MainWindow.cc;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < rw; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    o[i][j] = jTable1.getValueAt(i, j);
                    System.out.println("imj" + i + "," + j + "=" + o[i][j]);
                }
                if (String.valueOf(o[i][5]) == "") {
                    xdate=null;
                }
                else {
                                        xdate = new java.sql.Date(df.parse(String.valueOf(o[i][5])).getTime());

                }
                queries[i] = "insert into po_items values('" + poid + "','" + cc + "','" + o[i][1] + "'," + o[i][2] + "," + o[i][4] + ",'" + xdate + "','" + o[i][7] + "'," + o[i][8] + ")";
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < rw; k++) {
                System.out.println(queries[k]);
            }
            String query = "insert into tablex values('xx','yy')";
            con=CPool.getConnection();
            st=con.createStatement();
                con.setAutoCommit(false);
                for(int l=0;l<rw;l++)
                {
                    st.addBatch(queries[l]);
                }
                st.addBatch(query);
                st.executeBatch();
                con.commit();
            System.out.println(query);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            System.out.println(x.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
              CPool.closeConnection(con);
              CPool.closeStatement(st);
        }

    }
```

Comment: **Warning:** your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To avoid this vulnerability (and get some added benefits), use prepared statements and set parameters using the `set*` methods.

Answer (score 1):

you wouldn't know if a query is going to error out unless you execute/ fire the query.

However, what you can do is to group the query in a database transaction and do a commit if all works well and a rollback if any of the queries fail. You can use a try catch block to achieve this (do a rollback on exception; commit otherwise).

Comment: I'd like to add that he kind of already does that, doesn't he? If execBatch throws a SQLException, the con.commit won't be executed. Or am I missing something ...

Comment: @Fildor I don't see him do a rollback which is important to emulate the behavior of not having executed the query. The answer is also to emphasize that it's not easy to figure out whether a query is going to fail without executing it.

Answer (score 1):

If an exception happens, you execute neither `rollback` nor `commit` before closing the connection, which results in unspecified behavior. You must `rollback` whenever the `try` block didn't complete normally.

On a separate note, using the JDBC batching API will bring you performance only if you use it in combination with a `PreparedStatement`, batch entries varying only in the arguments to the same statement. As advised elsewhere, `PreparedStatement` is the way to go regardless if you want to be safe from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: An additional note: batching will only add performance (over `PreparedStatement`) if the database actually supports batching, otherwise the driver will just simulate batching. However, on database that do support batching it might actually bring a minor performance benefit even with normal `Statement`, because the driver might send all queries at once: Instead of the overhead of `N x (send query, receive query result)`, it becomes `send (N x queries), receive (N x query results)`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel +1 I also think that, if you consistently use statements of equal structure, you may experience a speedup even if the statement wasn't prepared. As always, subject to the particular driver. I don't want to dilute my main point, though, so I have refrained from including these subtleties in the answer.